# HTML UL Menu from XML

Tags: jquery, html, xml, menu

i am receiving xml structured data which is not nested and I need to create UL menu out of it. Data is receiver using .ajax jquery .. please for any idea. Even if I fix output of XML i don't know how to achive this.

Structure of XML (sample values) :

```
<data id="1">
   <skItem>Food</skItem>
   <psItem>Item1 </psItem>
   <vssItem>value </vssItem>
</data>

<data id="2">
   <skItem>Food</skItem>
   <psItem>Item2 </psItem>
   <vssItem>value2 </vssItem>
</data>

<data id="3">
   <skItem>Food</skItem>
   <psItem>Itee3 </psItem>
   <vssItem>value </vssItem>
</data>

<data id="4">
   <skItem>Car</skItem>
   <psItem>Item2 </psItem>
   <vssItem>value </vssItem>
</data>
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like exactly what you need:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/use-jquery-to-retrieve-data-from-an-xml-file/

Comment: thank you for answering .. i see i didn't attach an appropriet example .. my xml is gound 3 levels under ..